# Force a Specific Camera Aquisition Framerate in a realtime Matlab Loop

Tags: matlab, camera, real-time

I have a function running in real time controlling hardware timing, etc. I want  to be able to record video as well, so I've created a global video object in matlab, and set the triggering to manual. Right now, I have it so that each iteration of the realtime loop I record a frame and write it to disk. I'm changing it so that Ill record to memory till I hit some limit, and then writing to disk. However, I'd like to guarantee no matter how fast the real time loop is running, I only capture 15 frames per second.

Thinking about though, how can I make it so that I capture the 15 frames not so dramatically close to each other? If the real time loop is running lightning fast, the 15 frames will just be gathered at the "beginning" and capture almost no change that has occurred during that second. In other words, the faster real time loop is, the more my sampling will act like 1 frame per second (which has 14 other copies made).

For example,

```
% Main File
function start()

global vid;
global myLogger;
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_160x120');
src = getselectedsource(vid);
triggerconfig(vid, 'manual');
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
vid.LoggingMode = 'disk&memory';
imaqmem(512000000); % 512 MB
myLogger = VideoWriter('C:\Users\myname\Desktop\output.avi', 'Motion JPEG AVI');
myLogger.Quality = 50;
myLogger.FrameRate = 15;
vid.DiskLogger = myLogger;
src.FrameRate = '15.0000';
vid.ReturnedColorspace = 'grayscale';

start(vid);
open(myLogger);

initiateFastLoop();

close(myLogger);

stop(vid);


end
```

The real time piece:

```
function initiateFastLoop


global vid;
global myLogger;

while(flag)
    % perform lightning fast stuff
    frame = getsnapshot(vid);
    writeVideo(myLogger, frame);
end

end
```

The video generated is much higher framerate, and I don't want to capture a frame every single time realtime loop runs, and I don't want to set a simple upper limit because of the problem described above. Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you seen the other triggering properties, such as `TriggerFcn` or the `FramesAcquiredFcn`, and `FramesAcquiredFcnCount`? Unfortunately the documentation of these is a bit poor; the most information you seem to get is by doing an `imaqhelp videoinput`. Webcam is packed away in a box so I can't test this at the mo, hence the comment instead of answer.

Comment: yeah I tried looking around but like you said documentation is pretty bad at this point. I'm playing around with the idea of setting a matlab `timer` function that waits `66ms` (1000ms/15fps) and then records an image? Don't know the overhead on all that though.

Comment: You should be able to do, e.g., `vid.FramesAcquiredFcn = @(src, evt)myWriteVideoCallback(evt);` and then the `videoinput` object will call your callback every time it gets some frames (it will wait until there are `vid.FramesAcquiredCount` frames in the buffer before calling your function). You will want to pay attention to the `evt` input argument, as it probably contains frame data for one **or more** frames - so no need to use `getsnapshot`. This way you will acquire frames at the rate set by the device, not by some accident of coding.